# Tweets don't show up in people's notifications tab

Tags: twitter, notifications

When I tweet someone (mention them e.g.. @username) my tweet does not show up in their mentions. However, it can be seen by them on their timeline. I have tweeted multiple friends to check that this really is the case. All of my notifications are working normally.

I have another Twitter account, I used that to tweet others and that was working perfectly. I used both accounts on the same devices, so I think it's just my main account that has a problem. I also tweeted my second account from my original account (which is having the problem) and there was no notification.

I checked that all the settings on my second account are on and normal, but still, nothing. So, the problem is with my account, not others. I have deleted the twitter app multiple times, I tried to fix it on my laptop. Nothing is working.

Comment: I've had people start following me in 2078 and 1878, so twitter's code is far from perfect (and/or their messing with time travel means your mention notifications were delivered in the far past or will be delivered in the far future)